# How to add QTY Increasing and decreasing input in minicart hyva theme

Tags: mini-cart, magento2.4.6, qty, hyva

add QTY Increasing and decreasing input in minicart hyva theme (same as default magento)[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the cart drawer in Hyva (`Magento_Theme::html/cart/cart-drawer.phtml`).

Add this function to the [alpine.js](/questions/tagged/alpine.js) component:

```
updateItemQty(item) {
    this.isLoading = true;

    const formKey = hyva.getFormKey();
    const postUrl = BASE_URL + 'checkout/cart/updateItemQty/';

    let cart = {};
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('form_key', formKey);
    formData.append(`cart[${item.item_id}][qty]`, item.qty);

    fetch(postUrl, {
        "body": formData,
        "method": "POST",
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.redirected) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        } else if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            window.dispatchMessages && window.dispatchMessages([{
                type: 'warning',
                text: '<?= $escaper->escapeJs(__('Could not update item from quote.')) ?>'
            }]);
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    }).then(result => {
        window.dispatchMessages && window.dispatchMessages([{
            type: result.success ? 'success' : 'error',
            text: result.success
                ? '<?= $escaper->escapeJs(__('You updated the item.')) ?>'
                : result.error_message
        }], result.success ? 5000 : 0)
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('reload-customer-section-data'));
    }).finally(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
    });
},
```

And add the input node and a way to call the function, here is an example:

```
<!-- add this below the price of the item in the template -->
<!-- <template x-for="item in cartItems"> -->
<!-- ... -->
<div>
    <span>Update Qty: </p>
    <input x-model="item.qty" type="number" size="4" step="any" title="Qty" class="form-input" min="1" data-role="cart-item-qty">
    <button type="button" title="Update Shopping Cart Item" class="action update btn btn-secondary" x-on:click="updateItemQty(item)" x-cloak>Update</button>
</div>
```

It might need further testing and enhancement, but you can use the idea and improve on it.