# how to add qty input in mini cart Magento 2 using Hyva theme

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, hyva, hyva-themesmagento2-default-theme

Add QTY Increasing and decreasing input in mini cart hyva theme (same as default Magento 2)

Comment: Check this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/370455/how-to-add-qty-increasing-and-decreasing-input-in-minicart-hyva-theme

Comment: Can this be done without reloading this page? @LokeshNaik

Comment: @AdminSAB The answer is already based on `fetch` which does not reload the page.